# new to lists, function doesn't print list elements

Tags: c, list, linked-list

I am a beginner to C and am learning linked lists. I tried making functions to have everything organised but no matter what i do the function `print_list` doesn't print the values. The output is only START and END. I noticed that if I put the same block of code directly into the function that builds the lists, then it prints correctly. What am I doing wrong? (Also first time asking on stack overflow)
Thank you to whoever answers.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct nd
{
    int val;
    struct nd *next;
} node;
typedef node * Lista;

void print_list(node*currnode)
{
    printf("START -> ");
    while (currnode != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d -> ", currnode->val);
        currnode = currnode->next;
    }
    printf("END");
}
//reimpilista means "buildlist"
node*riempilista(Lista lis){
    node  *currentNode, *temp;
    int i,n;
    
    printf("how many nodes?\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        currentNode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  
        printf("Enter element %d : ", (i + 1));
        scanf("%d", &currentNode->val);
        
        if (i == 0)
        {
            temp = currentNode;
        }
        else
        {  
            temp->next = currentNode;
            temp = currentNode;
        }
    }

    temp->next = NULL;
    return lis;
}

int main(){
    Lista listautente=NULL;
    listautente=riempilista(listautente);
    print_list(listautente);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `riempilista` takes an argument named `lis`, does absolutely nothing with it, then returns it. So `listautente` will always be `NULL` in `main`

Comment: Aside: by singling out the first node as a special case, you aren't providing a (`NULL`) link for the `next` member. There should be no need to make a special case. For each node, you can copy the present head pointer to the `next` member and replace the head member with a pointer to the current node. So `currentNode->next = lis; lis = currentNode;`

Answer (score 0):

When you build the list you need to return the head of the list as a result. So you need to store the pointer to the first node. Then when adding a new node you need to know the previous node, so you need to store it as well. The last added node should have `next` field poiting to `NULL` otherwise you won't be able to determine the end of the list and will get an exception.

Here is your code slightly edited.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct nd {
    int val;
    struct nd *next;
} node;

typedef node *Lista;

void print_list(node *currnode) {
    printf("START -> ");
    while (currnode != NULL) {
        printf("%d -> ", currnode->val);
        currnode = currnode->next;
    }
    printf("END");
}

//reimpilista means "buildlist"
node *riempilista() {
     node *firstNode = NULL, *currentNode = NULL, *previousNode = NULL;
     int i, n;
    
    printf("how many nodes?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        currentNode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        
        printf("Enter element %d : ", (i + 1));
        scanf("%d", &currentNode->val);
        currentNode->next = NULL;
        
        if (i == 0) {
            firstNode = currentNode;
        }

        if (previousNode != NULL) {        
            previousNode->next = currentNode;
        }

        previousNode = currentNode;
    }

    return firstNode;
}

int main() {
    Lista listautente = riempilista();
    print_list(listautente);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix your program with minimal changes. Here it is:

Change

```
node  *currentNode, *temp;
```

to

```
node  *currentNode, *temp, *head;
```

Change

```
temp = currentNode;
```

to

```
temp = currentNode; head = temp;
```

Change

```
return lis;
```

to

```
return head;
```

Here is the link to the modified code:
https://onlinegdb.com/8cjqifgl2